# Jquery function not firing on initial load

Tags: javascript, jquery, load

I have a situation where I must wait for a *Specific image* to load, and then either swap out its src, or locate the next image and hide/show it.

What I need to happen is show a placeholder image (silhouette) until its main image is ready, and then hide the silhouette and show the main image. Very common stuff.

Problem is this jquery function does not fire on a new tab, or window... but if I hit f5 it works perfectly... but then again I open a new tab, and it wont  fire until I hit f5.

```
CSS:
.staffImage1, .staffImage2, .staffImage3, .staffImage4, .staffImage5 { display: none; }

Jquery:
$('.staffImage1, .staffImage2,.staffImage3,.staffImage4, .staffImage5')
    .load(function () {
        $(this).next('.sillhouette').hide();
        $(this).show();
        console.log("function fired")
    })
```

I get the log message only after refresh.

Something to be aware of is I am using the "First 14k" method to increase page speed, so maybe jquery just is not ready when the images are initially loaded the first time, but are cached and work after f5?

*Each* image must wait until its fully loaded, they are in a slider, so I need to show the first slides image as soon as its ready,I cannot wait until all 5 images are ready, as that would slow down the first slides image.

Any advice is appreciated, thank you

Comment: i think because  you assign `display:none` to all images

Comment: Hmm I initially used jquery to .hide() them, but figured this was a waste when css can do the same thing. This also created the same refresh error. I also I assume .show() is just jquery changing the CSS rule to block. Either way thank you, but hiding the images with .hide(), it still required a refresh to fire.

Comment: I think Amit is right. The browser will not load the images if they are not to be displayed according to the CSS. Since you're using jQuery perhaps you can look into an image loader plugin such as [this one](http://beatak.github.io/jquery-imageloader/).

Comment: If I initially hide them with jquery .hide() the error remains. I will take a look at the link, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This structure:

```
$('.staffImage1, .staffImage2,.staffImage3,.staffImage4, .staffImage5').load(...)
```

does not work to notify you when all the images have been loaded.  `.load()` only works on a single image at a time.  And, if the images are cached, they may already have finished loading before your jQuery even runs so you would miss the load event entirely.

The simplest work-around is to use the window load event when all page resources have finished loading:

```
$(window).load(function() {
    // all images are loaded here
});
```

It is also possible to monitor just those 5 images, but that is more work.  I've written code to do this before so I'll see if I can find that prior code.

---

Here's a jQuery plug-in function that monitors just specific images.  It will call its callback when all the images in the jQuery object are loaded:

```
// call the callback when all images have been loaded
// if all images are already loaded or there were no images in the jQuery
// object, then the callback will be called immediately
jQuery.fn.imgsLoaded = function(fn) {
    var cntRemaining = 0;
    function checkDone() {
        if (cntRemaining === 0) {
            fn();
        }
    }

    function imgDone() {
        --cntRemaining;
        checkDone();
        // remove event handlers to kill closure when done
        $(this).off("load error abort", imgDone);
    }

    this.each(function() {
        if (!this.tagName.toLowerCase() === "img" && !this.complete && this.src) {
            ++cntRemaining;
            $(this).on("load error abort", imgDone);
        }
    });
    checkDone();
    return this;
}
```

You could use it like this:

```
$('.staffImage1, .staffImage2,.staffImage3,.staffImage4, .staffImage5').imgsLoaded(function () {
    $(this).next('.sillhouette').hide();
    $(this).show();
    console.log("function fired")
});
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/zaoweyoo/

Comment: Oh I assumed each of the images would cause a new function to run, when each is loaded fully? As I get 5 logs  messages in the console. I do need a new function for each image that is loaded separately.

Comment: @Benji40 - perhaps `$(window).load(...)` might be the simplest option.

Comment: Hmm that may work, but because I am focusing on page speed, I dont want to wait until the entire doc is loaded(only each image specifically in the slider), hence using the first 14k method for above the fold content. But if there is no othter way around it I will use this, and mark it as correct.

Comment: @Benji40 - I added a custom solution to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Write jquery code 
    '$(document).ready(function(){
       //your code
    });'